# How to access a variable from a different controller to make a custom download action work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, routes

I have a resumes controller and a welcomes controller in my app. The welcomes controller has only an index action which is there for the root page. The purpose of the resumes controller is to upload(new/create), download(download) etc. pdf files as an logged in user and it works great so far.

I want to implement the resume download feature on the rootpage as well.(welcomes_controller /index).

**How can I accomplish this? 
Since I can not call the variable to access the resume model from the welcomes controller. How should the routes be? What should I modify on the welcomes_controller?**

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root 'welcomes#index'

  resources :resumes do
    get :download, on: :member
  end

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

**resumes_controller.rb**

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :catch_not_found
  before_action :find_resume, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :download ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
  end

  def new
    if @resume = current_user.resume
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      @resume = Resume.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @resume = current_user.build_resume(resume_params)
    if @resume.save
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @resume.update resume_params
      redirect_to @resume, notice: "Your resume was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @resume.destroy
    redirect_to new_resume_path, notice: "Your resume was successfully deleted!"
  end

  def download
    send_data @resume, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "attachment"
  end

  private

  def resume_params
    params.require(:resume).permit( :user_id, :download_file, :remove_download_file)
  end

  def find_resume
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  end

  def catch_not_found
    yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
  end

end
```

**resumes/show.html.erb**

```
...
...
<%= link_to "Download", download_resume_path(@resume), "data-turbolinks" => false %>
```

**welcomes_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access Resume model from welcome controller, although controller is welcome you can call Resume model see sample below

```
class WelcomesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # you can call Resume model frome here
    @resumes = Resume.all
  end

  def show
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```